# how can i fetch data from url location

Tags: php, json

I am working with the JSON in which I have to fetch the location of particular city e.g: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Vanguard,CA,%20United%20States&output=json

Now in PHP how can I write the code to fetch the "Point" data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) on in `php.ini`, you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). You can then parse with [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Vanguard,CA,%20United%20States&output=json'), TRUE);
```

`$json` is now an array of your JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_data=file_get_contents($url);
```

`allow_url_fopen` should be `on` in this case.

[Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) can be used as an alternate option

Answer (score 1):

I advice using the cURL lib for this. ([cUrL](http://nl2.php.net/curl)). It just offers more options and error handling then using alternatives like [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) etc.