# How do I use php to pull in json from a url for use as a variable?

Tags: php, json

I have a url where json is being dynamically loaded. I need to use php to pull in that json and use json_decode to get the info out of it. So far I have not been able to figure out how to get the actual json into my php. What is it that I need to do? Is there a "content" command for php?

Right now I'm trying:

```
print(json_decode('http://theurl.com'));
```

Comment: `print(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://theurl.com')));`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740665/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-url-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://theurl.com'));
```

You can also use cURL instead of `file_get_contents` for some extra speed and control, but it's relatively complicated to compared to `file_get_contents`, especially if you've never used it before.

Comment: cURL is neither faster nor does it offer more control than `file_get_contents` with a custom stream context attached.

Comment: does there need to be anything set up for json_decode to work? I've got the contents coming in, because if I load it in I can echo it, however when I try to use json_decode nothing is ever returned/echoed/printed.

Comment: @Ghost9 What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @Ghost9, and what OS you might need to install something like: `php-pecl-json` If you have installation privileges on your server.

Comment: I found the error. The json I'm trying to load had ( ) around it. I used substr($json, 1, -1); to get rid of it and now i'm getting results. Thanks!

Comment: @Ghost9 Oh haha well that's a lot simpler than not having JSON support installed :)